# Uncaught ReflectionException: 805

Tags: laravel, git, deployment, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to clone my project to server.
after finish the git,
I got the php errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in 

/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:805
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(687): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(633): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
#5 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php(66): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
#6 /var/www/laravel/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/ServiceProvider.php(28 in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 807
```

here is my .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://test.com

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=Test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

my composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "laraveldaily/laravel-invoices": "^1.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
    }
}
```

after i clone my project, I gave laravel folder Permissions

```
sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/laravel
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/storage
```

my laravel.log is empty
any command will bringback the errors.
such as: composer dump-autoload
composer update ...
php artisan .. clear cache...
Please help.
Im new to laravel.
the project are running ok on my local pc using xamp.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might get the same issues, I find out that I remove:

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class); $app->configure('dompdf');
```

in: bootstrap/app.php
and run composer update again.